# Publisher attribute of the Identity element in AppxManifest (Cordova)

Tags: cordova, windows-phone

I am trying to publish windows phone cordova application on windows store.
I build application with:

```
cordova build widows --release
```

When upload, I am getting error

```
Package acceptance validation error: The Publisher attribute of the Identity element in the app manifest of file CordovaApp.xxx.appx is CN=$username$, which doesn't match your publisher ID: CN=xxxxxxxxxxxxx.
```

I tried associate app with defining next line config.xml:

```
  <preference name="windows-publisher-id" value="-appCN-" />
```

but there is stil:

```
 <Identity Name="xxx" Publisher="CN=$username$" Version="1.0.0.0" ProcessorArchitecture="neutral" />
```

in AppxManifest.xml after build.
How can I specify CN value? (I am not using Visual Studio)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing the `Publisher` attribute of the `Identity` tag in /platforms/windows/package.phone.appxmanifest

EDIT:
There is now a better solution (see cadesalaberry's answer below)

Comment: This works, but I wish we could define it on config.xml

Comment: I do not think manually changing files inside platforms folder is a good solution...

Answer (score 1):

As per https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/guide/platforms/win8/index.html#signing-an-app

You can now use a `build.json` file aside your `config.xml` which would look like this:

```
 {
      "windows": {
          "release": {
              "packageCertificateKeyFile": "c:\\path-to-key\\keycert.pfx"
              "publisherId": "CN=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
          }
      }
  }
```